# Struct property closure just run once in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

Have any idea to let closure just run once.

Every time I call the `APIResult`. the property which is `priceSortedItems` will print "123". I want make it run once  to reduce memory usage. Thanks.

```
struct APIResult {

    var aryItem = [Item]()

    var priceSortedItems: [Item] {

        print("123")

        let sortedItems = self.aryItem.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
            Double(item1.Value)! > Double(item2.Value)!
        })

        return sortedItems
    }
}
```

Comment: _stored_ and _computed_ properties are different.

Answer (score 3):

Your property is counted property with *getter*. That means every time you need to get your variable, code inside getter gets executed and you get new value from *getter*.

If you want to initialize your variable just once, use `lazy` variable which gets initialized once when is needed:

```
lazy var priceSortedItems: [Item] = {

    print("123")

    let sortedItems = self.aryItem.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
        Double(item1.Value)! > Double(item2.Value)!
    })

    return sortedItems
}()
```

Comment: do you know what does the OP's sentence "Every time I call the APIResult" mean? if it means something like let a = APIResult() there will be no difference ...  Most likely declare it as a function is the better option here. I don't believe, that sorted items assignment should be called only once :)

Comment: yes, I agree, except it doesn't work as a setter and will return the "actual data", depends on current state of the APIResult object.

Comment: But I got an error. 'lazy' must not be used on a computed property

Comment: @JimmyLee didn’t you forget to equal symbol? `lazy va priceSortedItems: [Item] = {

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update `priceSortedItems` once `aryItem` changed. You should do like this.

```
struct APIResult {

    var aryItem = [Item]() {
        didSet {
            priceSortedItems = aryItem.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
                Double(item1.Value)! > Double(item2.Value)!
            })
        }
    }

    var priceSortedItems = [Item]()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func priceSortedItems() ->[Item] {

    print("123")

    let sortedItems = self.aryItem.sorted(by: { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
        Double(item1.Value)! > Double(item2.Value)!
    })

    return sortedItems
}
```

You can create it as a function.